# Printing same value if we call function inside the loop. Can you help me to resolve this issue

Tags: javascript, postman

Printing same value if we call function inside the loop. Can you help me to resolve this issue. pls check the image

It outputs this:

"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"
"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"
"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"
"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"
"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"
"isinRes 8  SA0007879782"

check below code and help me to fix this :)
[Issue- Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSekc.png)

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var dat = bodyData.DAT.SYMS[i];
    var dataArr = dat.split('|');
    

    //Verify symbol with seach key
    var symbolRes = dataArr[1];
    pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[1] + " :  Verify symbol name with seach key", function () {
        pm.expect(symbolRes).is.to.includes(sk);
    });

    //Verfy Exchange with input exchange value
    var exgRes = dataArr[0];
    pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[0] + " :  Verify symbol name with req exchange name", function () {
        pm.expect(exg).is.to.equals(exgRes);
    });


    //Getting Symbol details from DB API
    //var insTypeDB;
    //var sectorDB;
    var isinDB;
    //var isinRes = dataArr[6];
    pm.sendRequest("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080/ords/unidata/symbol/symbol/" + dataArr[1], function (err, response) {

        var resBoday = response.json()
        //insTypeDB = resBoday.items[0].instrument_type_id;
        //sectorDB = resBoday.items[0].sector_id;
        isinDB = resBoday.items[0].isin_code;
        ////var intInsTypeDB = parseInt(insTypeDB);
        //console.log("insTypeDB " + insTypeDB);
        //console.log("sectorDB " + sectorDB);
        console.log("isinDB "+i+" "+isinDB);
        
        //Verify ISIN code with DB API
        pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[1] + " :  Verify ISIN code with DB", function () {
            var isinRes = dataArr[6];
            console.log("isinRes "+ i +"  "+ isinRes);
            pm.expect(isinDB).is.to.equals(isinRes);
        });
        
    });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should use let instead of var to making sure that you'll have block scope and non of those variables are being redefined